# Not handling authentication, but need claims and cookie

Tags: asp.net, authentication, cookies, owin

I am creating a new asp.net MVC 5 application.  Authentication is handled by a third party using smart cards.  Once a user is authenticated by the third party, I am sent the user's unique ID (inside the http header) which I match up against my database in order to find relevant information about said user (roles, display name, etc.).

Currently, on every page request, the sent user ID is compared against the database, and checks are performed to ensure the user has the proper permissions to view the requested page.  While this works, it sure seems like a bunch of needless database hits when all the user information could just be stored in a cookie.

If I was using Individual User Accounts for authentication, what I am looking to do would simply be built in using Identity and OWIN.  But since I am not handling the authentication, but merely the authorization, is there a way to use all the nice features of Identity and OWIN (claims and cookies specifically)?  If not, how might one go about this?

Also, of particular interest to me is when a role is added or removed.  Using OWIN with Individual User Accounts, updating the cookie is as simple as logging the user out, and then back in immediately in the background.  That functionality would also be desired for any solution presented.

Any insight would be extremely helpful.  Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.  Found a great article that really helped:

http://www.khalidabuhakmeh.com/asp-net-mvc-5-authentication-breakdown-part-deux

Answer (score 0):

You could do what you're asking by directly storing values in a custom cookie, but for your purposes it sounds to me like you might be more interested in utilizing [sessions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581%28v=vs.140%29.aspx) to track that info.  This will keep all of your actual data stored server-side, which is more secure as it isn't vulnerable to cookie modification and it allows you more freedom to control the state (for your role example, you wouldn't have to "update" the cookie at all, just update the session variable on the server side to add or remove the role as needed).